# Adding typing to a function using TypeVar with restricted types

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, mypy

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar), `TypeVar` serve as the parameters for generic types as well as for **generic function** definitions. It also allow us to restrict the possible types for our generic type or function.

If I run the code below with mypy it will correctly identify `y` as being an `int` and `z` as being a `float`.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Any

Array = TypeVar("Array")

X = TypeVar("X", int, float, str, complex)


def identity(x: X) -> X:
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = identity(5)
    z = identity(5.5)
    reveal_type(y)
    reveal_type(z)
```

However, if I change the definition of `X` to `X = TypeVar("X", int, float, str, complex, Any)` then the revealed type of `y` and `z` that I get from mypy is just `Any`.

My question is: Is this a bug or am I wrongly using `TypeVar`? How should I type this function then if TypeVar is the wrong way to go here?

The funny thing is that if instead I define `X` as `X = TypeVar("X", Any, int, float, str, complex)` then I get the correct revealed types for `y` and `z` as before, but the documentation about `TypeVar` does not say anything about the order and this might be just an implementation detail and it would be fragile to depend on it. Putting `Any` after `int, float,` will reveal the types of `y` and `z` as `complex`, which is wrong.

---

Note: What I actually want to add to the constrained types is the numpy array, but since it have no typing information mypy interprets it as just `Any` and it has the same effect.

Comment: Why would you put `Any` in a `TypeVar` definition? Including a type means restricting to that type so using `Any` here means "X is restricted to any type".

Comment: That's only in this minimum example. What I want to add is the numpy.ndarray type, but since it has no type hinting it is interpreted as Any. There is a project to create stubs for numpy, but even if I add the stubs the same problem would still occur with any other library without types. Therefore I think the question makes sense.

Comment: You can add your own local stubs for untyped libs (they don't have to be complete, so define only stuff you need to pass typechecking in your code), or alias unknown types for typechecking specifically (although IMO it doesn't always look nice in code).

Comment: @hoefling That seems like a good long term solution, although I still think the behavior of TypeVar is strange and something I have to keep an eye for.